# Error when run Amplify Configure command on windows

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, aws-amplify, server-rendering

I've followed these step in https://dev.to/rakannimer/server-side-rendered-real-time-web-app-with-next-js-aws-amplify-graphql-2j49 to setup Amplify but I think, I have missed something that's why I cannot run amplify configure or amplify init in cmd on Windows 
It shows the error below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1zqL.png)

Comment: Well if you Google something like "the file .ps1 is not digitally signed" there's a bunch of posts with possible solution already on SO. Have you tried those? If so which one, so we can narrow it down. Also, please post the error message text itself, not a picture of it.

Comment: Tks Jayce this is my first post. i'll remember that